# How to mock a function inside a http request?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am using pytest, I have a test like:

```py
def test_fun1(client):
    rsp = client.get(url)
```

Inside this get url which in my flask server, their is a function `fun2()`,

```py
# restful api
def get():
    res1 = fun2()
    # do thing on res1
    return res2
```

I want mock this `fun2()`, in my pytest `test_fun1`, `with patch.object()` and `Mock()`not work, any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the test code as well. Also, can you show where `fun2` is defined? Is it imported or defined in the same file as your `def get()`?

Comment: The test_client of flask runs the tests against an actual server. So mocks would be either not even read or loaded after the fact.
What you should really do here is to test `fun2` separately first and then the test client for flask should be used for testing the web server only (no mocks).
Eventually, for education purposes, you should know you can mock `fun2` but it requires to mock extra things too.